# filter list of dictionaries based on a particular value of a key in that dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows

```
dict = {2308:[{'name':'john'},{'age':'24'},{'employed':'yes'}],3452:[{'name':'sam'},{'age':'45'},{'employed':'yes'}],1234:[{'name':'victor'},{'age':'72'},{'employed':'no'}]}
```

I want to filter out the above dictionary to new dictionary named new_dict whose age >30.

I tried the following. As I new to programming, could not get the logic.

`new_dict =[var for var in dict if dict['age']>30]`

But I know it is list of dictionaries, so is there any way I can get the new list dictionaries with age >30

Comment: A couple things:  1. You should definitely not call things `dict`.  That shadows the built-in and will cause you all sorts of problems later.  2.  You don't have a list of dictionaries.  You have a dictionary of lists of dictionaries, which is an incredibly convoluted data structure to work from.  Do you have any control over the input data format?  I'd try to clean that up _first_.  It'll simplify your task _considerably_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following dict comprehension (assuming you store the dictionary in variable `d` rather than `dict`, which would shadow the built-in `dict` class):

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if any(int(s.get('age', 0)) > 30 for s in v)}
```

This returns:

```
{3452: [{'name': 'sam'}, {'age': '45'}, {'employed': 'yes'}], 1234: [{'name': 'victor'}, {'age': '72'}, {'employed': 'no'}]}
```

Comment: Very nice after posting my answer I realized you just did everything I did with a one liner, amazing work

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
people = {
    2308:[
        {'name':'john'},{'age':'24'},{'employed':'yes'}
    ],
    3452:[
        {'name':'sam'},{'age':'45'},{'employed':'yes'}
    ],
    1234:[
        {'name':'victor'},{'age':'72'},{'employed':'no'}
    ]
}

people_over_30 = {}

for k, v in people.items():
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if int(v[i].get('age', 0)) > 30:
            people_over_30[k] = [v]


print(people_over_30)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 quote.py 
> {3452: [[{'name': 'sam'}, {'age': '45'}, {'employed': 'yes'}]], 1234: [[{'name': 'victor'}, {'age': '72'}, {'employed': 'no'}]]}
> ```

**Comments**

Unless this is your desired structure for this particular code, I would suggest reformatting your dictionary to look like this

```
people = {
    2308:
        {'name':'john','age':'24','employed':'yes'}
    ,
    3452:
        {'name':'sam','age':'45','employed':'yes'}
    ,
    1234:
        {'name':'victor','age':'72','employed':'no'}

}
```

And then your work would be much simpler and able to handle with this instead

```
for k, v in people.items():
    if int(v.get('age', 0)) > 30:
        people_over_30[k] = [v]
```